# Graphics on a high resolution display

Tags: graphics

I recently switched over to a laptop with a really high resolution display and now all of my .tex files with graphics are broken. Any idea what's happening here / how to fix it?

Comment: What is your exact problem ? Are the figures/graphics files not visualised properly in editor viewer/ pdf reader ? What do you mean by graphics are broken ? not able to load graphics files ?

Comment: Could you please inform your Operating System and your (La)TeX distribution?

Comment: I'm also wondering about these broken graphics. I always use .eps figures since it's vector file, and can scale easily.

Comment: i don't think it has any relations with latex .... if you had bad source image ... they will be bad regardless of graphic card , the only think that you experience is that you have moved to new environment and settings are not identical to previous.